# InvocationTargetException in Yarn task with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, apache-apex

While running `Kafka` -> `Apache Apex` ->`Hbase`, it is saying following exception in Yarn tasks:

```
com.datatorrent.stram.StreamingAppMasterService: Application master, appId=4, clustertimestamp=1479188884109, attemptId=2
2016-11-15 11:59:51,068 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service com.datatorrent.stram.StreamingAppMasterService failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.newInstance(AbstractFileSystem.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:330)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
```

And my DataTorrent log showing the following exception. I am running the app which communicates Kafka -> Apex -> Hbase streaming application.

```
 Connecting to ResourceManager at hduser1/127.0.0.1:8032
 16/11/15 17:47:38 WARN client.EventsAgent: Cannot read events for application_1479208737206_0008: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /user/hduser1/datatorrent/apps/application_1479208737206_0008/events/index.txt
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1893)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1834)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1814)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1786)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:552)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2036)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2034)
```

Adding the code :

```
public void populateDAG(DAG dag, Configuration conf){
KafkaSinglePortInputOperator in
  = dag.addOperator("kafkaIn", new KafkaSinglePortInputOperator());

in.setInitialOffset(AbstractKafkaInputOperator.InitialOffset.EARLIEST.name());
LineOutputOperator out = dag.addOperator("fileOut", new LineOutputOperator());

dag.addStream("data", in.outputPort, out.input);}
```

> LineOutputOperator extends AbstractFileOutputOperator

```
private static final String NL = System.lineSeparator();
private static final Charset CS = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

@NotNull
private String baseName;

@Override
public byte[] getBytesForTuple(byte[] t) {
  String result = new String(t, CS) + NL;
  return result.getBytes(CS);
}

@Override
protected String getFileName(byte[] tuple) {
 return baseName;
}

public String getBaseName() { return baseName; }
public void setBaseName(String v) { baseName = v; }
```

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Seeing the logs I believe the operator is not able to find some file. This can be either due to incorrect path settings (check the file path in HDFS) or the file path doesn't exist (less likely). Provide some more details like operators used which might be helpful in identifying the issue.

Comment: I implemented my custom apex operator which extends BaseOperator and implemented process() & endWindow() method.

And two variables input and output and their classes are DafaultInput and Output Operators.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share some details about your environment like what version of hadoop and apex ? Also, which log does this exception appear in ?

Just as a simple sanity check, can you run the simple maven archetype generated application described at: http://docs.datatorrent.com/beginner/

If that works, try running the fileIO and kafka applications at:
https://github.com/DataTorrent/examples/tree/master/tutorials

If those work ok we can look at the details of your code.

Comment: Hi i ran example of Kafka and it is not working properly and works for PiDemo and randomNumbers.

My environment :
OS : Ubuntu-14.04
Kafka: 2_11.0.10.0.1.0
Apex : 3.5.0
Hbase : 1.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,

The problem related to expiry of my license, So reinstalled new one and works fine for actual code.